# Change string in a date format to another format

Tags: ruby, date

I have a string like this (YYYYMMDD):

> 20120225

And I want to have a string like this (MM/DD/YYYY):

> 02/25/2012

What's a good way of doing this in Ruby? I have thought about converting the first string to a Date, and then change the format. Or just treating the string and getting the parts I want and build the new string.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Parsing it](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) then [formatting it](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) is the best solution:

```
Date.parse("20120225").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")  #=> "02/25/2012"
```

Comment: it's the worst solution actually. if original date format is knows then use one of countless date/time factory methods to create the object. P.S. just recently i have improved speed of one of log importing scripts by 15 (!!!) times simply by dropping that Date.parse thing

Answer (score 10):

strptime parses the string representation of date with the specified template and creates a date object.

```
Date.strptime('20120225', '%Y%m%d').strftime("%m/%d/%Y")  #=> "02/25/2012"
```

Comment: cleanest solution

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun how about:

```
'20120225'.unpack('A4A2A2').rotate.join('/')
```

Comment: Works great - I used '2012-02-25'.unpack('A4xA2xA2').rotate.join('/') to get "02/25/2012".

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with regular expressions:

```
s1 = '20120225'
s2 = "$2/$3/$1" if s1 =~ /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/
```

Or if you're sure of the format of your string and have performance issues, I think the best solution is

```
s2 = s1[4..5] + '/' + s1[6..7] + '/' + s1[0..3]
```

But if you have no performance needs, I think the solution of Andrew Marshall is better because it checks the date validity.