# My date format : 09/28/2012 16:35:34 , I want the date format like : 2012-09-28T16:35:34 , using gsub

Tags: ruby, regex, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby - Change string in a date format to another format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649268/ruby-change-string-in-a-date-format-to-another-format)

My date format : `09/28/2012 16:35:34`, I want the date to be formatted like: `2012-09-28T16:35:34`, I need to compile the code in jruby.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to convert the date to something more useful:

```
require 'date'
dt = DateTime.strptime "09/28/2012 16:35:34", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
# => #<DateTime: 2012-09-28T16:35:34+00:00 (106107805067/43200,0/1,2299161)>
```

Now you can do any transformation:

```
dt.strftime '%FT%T'
# => "2012-09-28T16:35:34"
```

This also raises an exception when the date format is wrong, which is useful to notice when things break.

For more Information see the [Apidocs for `Date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/).

Comment: Thanks , what if i need to convert my_system_date (which is in format 09/28/2012 16:35:34 and i am getting it using system_date function) to same format 2012-09-28T16:35:34 ??

Comment: `my_system_date = DateTime.strptime(system_date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%FT%T')` i guess... ugly but works

Answer (score 0):

Find

```
(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+) ([\d:]+)
```

replace with

```
$3-$1-$2T$4
```

[Here](http://rubular.com/r/XR45DYUaw9) you can see the groups (which in the regex are the parts in `()`), $1 is the first group, $2 the second and so on. Basically you need to reorder the groups putting `-` in the middle and `T` before the hour.